# Does python have atomic CompareAndSet operation?

Tags: python, atomic

I need to use atomic CompareAndSet operation in my python program, but I didn't find reference about how to use it.

Does python provide such atomic function?

Thank you.

Comment: CPython has a GIL, so something like this is unnecessary at least in that implementation. You can use a lock for explicit synchronization

Comment: Thank you, Niklas. I have a lock version of the program, I just want to build a lock-free one and compare the performance.

Comment: Python doesn't have these kinds of low-level primitives because it is an interpreted language. If lock-freeness and performance is of concern, maybe you should use a compiled language

Comment: The GIL doesn't make this irrelevant, because Python still has threads (which is why it has a GIL!). But yes, the performance argument is perhaps more true — but in IronPython and Jython where neither has a GIL it obviously matters more, and in PyPy the performance argument is far less true.

Answer (score 2):

From the [`atomics`](https://pypi.org/project/atomics/) library:

```py
import atomics


a = atomics.atomic(width=4, atype=atomics.INT)

# set to 5 if a.load() compares == to 0
res = a.cmpxchg_strong(expected=0, desired=5)
print(res.success)
```

Note: I am the author of this library